# Android market publish problem

Tags: android, google-play

I just published my app and I can't find it on android market. Title is Nine Board TicTacToe.

This is from my developer console:

Supported Devices:
This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest.
Screen layouts: NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features

```
android.hardware.wifi
android.hardware.telephony
android.hardware.touchscreen
```

This application is available to over 461 devices.

minSdkVersion is 1

```
package="alencaljkusic.nineboardtictactoe"
```

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to see your app instantly after publishing it is going to the Android Market online straight to your package:
https://market.android.com/details?id=alencaljkusic.nineboardtictactoe

Comment: I know, just, it's not there :D

Comment: If it's still not there it's definitely a problem on your hand

Answer (score 0):

If you published it correctly you have to wait some minutes to let the changes to be done by the Android Market system.

It is **NOT** instant :)

Comment: I know, I published it a few hours from now :D. I see that a lot of people had a similar problem, but there is no exact solution.

Comment: I figured out that my Wildfire on which i tested app is not supported :P .
Can anyone please try to find it on any other device. Thanks

Comment: There's no F way I'm installing this with all the permissions you've asked for...

Answer (score 0):

My app shows that it supports a screen layout of SMALL, as well as NORMAL LARGE XLARGE.

> Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE

Did you manually set up the [supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) element in your AndroidManifest XML?  If not, then the problem might be because your `minSdkVersion` is set to 1.  The supports-screens link above seems to suggest some of these features only came along in API version 4.  I suggest you set your `minSdkVersion` to 4 and retry.

One other tip: use the Browser on your device to search for your app in the Market.  Once you've logged in, it will explicitly tell you if the app is supported for your device.